# Unobtrusive validation - added rule only works when an existing field is in place

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to add a required rule dynamically to a radio button list.

The example below works though when the 'Name' row is removed the validation now longer fires.

It appears there needs to be a field with data-val attributes on the page for the validation plugin to start watching the form.

How can I add dynamic rules to a page with no existing unobstrusive fields?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container body-content">
    <form action="" method="post">

        <!-- When below row is commented out validation no longer fires -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Name required" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row dynamic_checkbox_container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Dynamic Checkbox</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Yes
                <input id="CheckBox" name="CheckBox" type="radio" value="True"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                No
                <input id="CheckBox" name="CheckBox" type="radio" value="False"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CheckBox" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Go" name="go"/>
    </form>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".dynamic_checkbox_container input").each(function() {

            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "This field is required."
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you've presented should be working.  The plugin does not need `data-val` attributes...  only a `name`.  However, you don't need to use the `.rules('add')` method for something so simple.  Just include a class of `required` or the HTML5 `required="required"` attribute on the field.

Comment: Quote:  *"How can I add dynamic rules to a page with no existing unobstrusive fields?"*  ~ Are you using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin or not?  If not, then you must also call the `.validate()` method to initialize the jQuery Validate plugin on your form.

Comment: Hi Sparky - if you run the code it will work, but when you comment out the name row (the first one) it no longer works. Yes I'm using the unobstrusive validation plugin. I've used CDN version of all the plugins to make it easy to verify the issue for any posters. Regards Steve

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle demo of this problem.  Removing the Name row should have no bearing on anything.

Comment: Your view is makes no sense and could not possibly post back anything meaningful. Apart from duplicate `id`'s for the checkboxes (invalid html) you have 2 checkboxes with values `true` and `false` which means they always have a value so they are always valid. And you cant mix unobtrusive validation with manually creating rules.  And why do you have 2 checkboxes for the same property - what happens if none are checked or both are checked? What are you actually trying to do? And why are you manually generating html instead of binding to a model with strongly typed html helpers?

Comment: Stephen: Id's do not get posted back and if I use different id's then the validation does not bind. It's the name, value 'and' checked status that are important. I want a yes/no check box with two values - one checkbox would work fine but need to fit a client spec. This is the HTML output, wanted to make it easy for people to reproduce the issue and suggest a workourand.

Comment: I stated that duplicate `id` are invalid html, not that they get posted back (and removing or changing the `id` attribute has got nothing to do with it - in fact its typical when rendering radio buttons to give unique `id`'s). A `required` validation works by inspecting the `value` attribute of the element and validation fails if its `null` (empty string). Since the value of `CheckBox` will have a value of either "True"` or "False" then its always valid so you `rule` is pointless.

Comment: Agreed, they are. Though it is not the 'value' in the case of radio buttons it is a combintion of 'value' and the checked property. Still working on this and have found validation works when id's are omiited so I'm fixing that. The question of why validaiton only works when the text box is present remains unanswered.

Comment: @CountZero, The `checked` property has nothing to do with it (other than to determine which radio button is selected). If the 1st is selected, the posted value will be `CheckBox: True` and if the second is selected then it will be `CheckBox: False`. Not sure what you mean by _"validation only works when the text box is present"_ - the only validation that is ever performed will be on the textbox. If you remove the textbox, there is nothing to validate.

Comment: CountZero: I am able to reproduce the problem you're experiencing. Yes, Id's has to be unique (on all elements) however, in this case that has nothing to do with your actual question. When I remove first row from page validation doesn't work. If I add data-val="true" to the first CheckBox validation works (with or without Name row is present). I changed the checkbox Ids to CheckBox1 and CheckBox2. When Name row isn't present and data-val="true" isn't present I get the JS error Error: Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference from jquery.validate.js.

Comment: Put as answer and I'll accept. Bit of a blast from past.